# Do $\int_0^\infty \cos(\ln(x))/x\;dx$ and/or $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x)/\sqrt{x}\;dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Per the title, do the integrals  $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(\ln(x))}{x}\,dx$ and/or $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ converge?

**Attempt**

I've no idea how to approach this. Dirchlet test doesn't tell me they converge/diverge, and the functions aren't nonnegative so I'm not sure if I can use the comparison test...

Comment: According to wolfram-alpha the second integral is approximately, $4.09808...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second integral, I would rewrite $\ln(\sin x)$ as $\ln(x)+\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$.  The second term in the numerator is bounded, and as for the first, note that $\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x}<x^{-2/3}$ for sufficiently small $x$, which follows for example from l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Using your hint I can show $ln(r)/\sqrt{r}$ exists using comparison. Am I right that for $ln(sinr/r)/\sqrt{r}$, the integral exists because the function is continuous/bounded in $(0,\pi/2]$, and so the sum of these two exists?

Comment: @rol44: Right for the first part.  For the second, not quite what you said; because $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, it follows that $\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$ is bounded on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, so the second integral can be compared to $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: But since $ln(sinr/r)/\sqrt{r}$ is bounded in the same interval (since the limit at 0 is 0), wouldn't that guarantee the integral's existence without need for comparison?

Comment: @rol44: Oh yeah, thanks, silly me.  Come to think of it, comparing directly to $x^{-2/3}$ in the first place might even be easier.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's probably the quickest way...
Okay, I think this question is answered. I'm choosing Jonas's answer since it has more votes at this time, though both answers are equally useful. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, can you go on with the following indefinite integral
$$
\int \frac{\cos(\ln(x))}{x}dx = \sin(\ln(x))?
$$

Sivaram's comment may have given you an idea for the second one. (The goal is to show convergence.) I would like to do integration by part first for the indefinite integral, 
$$
\int\frac{\ln(\sin x) }{\sqrt x}dx = 2\int\ln(\sin x)d(\sqrt x) = 
2\ln(\sin x)\sqrt{x}-2\int\sqrt {x}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}dx
$$
and then treat $\ln(\sin x)\sqrt{x}$ and $\int\sqrt {x}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}dx$ separately.

Comment: Oooh, awesome. Can't believe I missed that.
Do you have a useful hint for the second integral?